# How to filter null object from streaming in flatmap

Tags: java, java-stream

I have safe guarded the first stream for NPE,but second stream can also throw NPE,below is the snippet:

```
 Set<TestObj> vals = Optional.ofNullable(testObjs)
                    .orElse(Collections.emptySet())
                    .stream()
                    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                    .flatMap(testObj -> getObjVal(testObj.getId()).getObj().stream())
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

If getObjVal(String id) is returning null ,second stream will throw NPE.

Below code is preventing the second NPE,but I feel its not a good way to do so:

```
Set<TestObj> vals = Optional.ofNullable(testObjs)
                    .orElse(Collections.emptySet())
                    .stream()
                    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                    .filter(testObj -> getObjVal(testObj.getId()) != null)
                    .flatMap(testObj->getObjVal(testObj.getId()).getObj().stream())
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Need to use vals in another place where subsequent calls will be made if vals is not empty.
Is there any better way to prevent NPE here, I tried using Optional inside flat map ,but iths throwing syntax error.

Comment: `.map(testObj::getId).map(id -> getObjVal(id)).filter(Objects::nonNull).map(objVal -> objVal.getObj()).flatMap(obj -> obj.stream())`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the duplicated call to `getObjVal` by doing it as a `map` before the `filter`.

```
Set<TestObj> vals = Optional.ofNullable(testObjs)
                    .orElse(Collections.emptySet())
                    .stream()
                    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                    .map(testObj -> getObjVal(testObj.getId()))
                    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                    .map(TestObject::getObj)
                    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```